# Disable Back Button Samsung Smatwatch

Tags: java, android, android-studio, wear-os

I am developing an app that always works in the foreground for smartwatches. I use a samsung watch, it has two buttons (back and home)and i can't manage to deactivate them by code, so that i can't act on them.

Right now I have this for the back button, but it doesn't work. For the home button I don't know what to do.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onPause();
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    activityManager.moveTaskToFront(getTaskId(), 0);
}
```

could someone help me?

Comment: You are unlikely to be able to override the home button -- that is for the user to be able to have control over their watch. The only way to avoid that is for your app to be the watch face app (the rough equivalent of being the launcher app on a phone). The code you have in `onBackPressed()` is truly bizarre (for example, never call `super.onPause()` from anywhere other than `onPause()`).

Comment: `onBackPressed()` is generally not used anymore. See https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back for documentation about customizing back navigation in modern Android app development.

Comment: @CommonsWare how would you do it, then?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not know what "it" is. I also do not know why you think your app should always be in the foreground. And I do not know if you plan to distribute this app how you intend to convince Google to relax its [Wear OS quality guidelines](https://developer.android.com/docs/quality-guidelines/wear-app-quality), such as WO-V3. So, it is difficult to provide you with advice for addressing your business concerns in a way that matches platform and user expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "disable" the back button you just **call the onBackPressed without it's super**...

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //super.onBackPressed();
}
```

About the moveTaskToFront of your code doesn't make much sense, as it is already on foreground, otherwise the onBackPressed wouldn't be called...

**About the home button, I don't think you can override it's function**...